# How to set title, META and Keyword tag for each post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to set the Title, Keyword, Meta tag for each post when creating a new post.

Is there any simple plugin for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in one SEO Pack has everything you are looking for:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/